# Creating a view where PostgreSQL shows the first 100 rows of a specific field, then moves to the next one

Tags: sql, postgresql, list, rows

I'm still learning the tricks and trade of PostgreSQL. I need a way of taking data and giving me the first 100 rows of each dataset.

My problem:

I have a table on the server that has over 60 columns. One column has the **country**. I need a breakdown where I get the first 100 rows by each country alphabetically.

There are 70 countries in this table. So the total results should be 7,000. How do I break this down?

Comment: Providing code here would be useful. Please see the how to ask guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Use ROW_NUMBER analytic function:

```
CREATE VIEW my_View AS
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...... col60
FROM (
   SELECT *,
        row_number() over (Partition by country ) as Rn
   FROM table
) x
WHERE rn <= 100
ORDER BY country
```

---

Thie above will give 100 random records for each country.  If you do not want such a randomness, then please use `ORDER BY some_column`clause in that way:

```
row_number() over (Partition by country ORDER BY country) as Rn
```

Comment: `row_number()`  requiere `ORDER BY`

Comment: @JUan Carlos [The documentation of window_definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) says that ORDER BY is optional.

Comment: Maybe optional. But if you dont include the order you will get 100 random rows, not the top 100 alphabetical.

Comment: @Juan Carlos, yes you are right, I've updated the answer, thank you for pointing that.